# Freezing Graph in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have trained a neural network and have generated a model folder with `.ckpt`, `.index`, etc files from it. The following is code I am using to generate a `.pb` file; however, I receive the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'model_checkpoint_path'

Does anyone assist me with solving the problem?

```
dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

def freeze_graph(model_dir, output_node_names):
"""Extract the sub graph defined by the output nodes and convert 
all its variables into constant 
Args:
    model_dir: the root folder containing the checkpoint state file
    output_node_names: a string, containing all the output node's names, 
                        comma separated
"""
if not tf.gfile.Exists(model_dir):
    raise AssertionError(
        "Export directory doesn't exists. Please specify an export "
        "directory: %s" % model_dir)

if not output_node_names:
    print("You need to supply the name of a node to --output_node_names.")
    return -1

# We retrieve our checkpoint fullpath
checkpoint = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(model_dir)
input_checkpoint = checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path

# We precise the file fullname of our freezed graph
absolute_model_dir = "/".join(input_checkpoint.split('/')[:-1])
output_graph = absolute_model_dir + "/frozen_model.pb"

# We clear devices to allow TensorFlow to control on which device it will load operations
clear_devices = True

# We start a session using a temporary fresh Graph
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    # We import the meta graph in the current default Graph
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(input_checkpoint + '.meta', clear_devices=clear_devices)

    # We restore the weights
    saver.restore(sess, input_checkpoint)

    # We use a built-in TF helper to export variables to constants
    output_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
        sess, # The session is used to retrieve the weights
        tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(), # The graph_def is used to retrieve the nodes 
        output_node_names.split(",") # The output node names are used to select the usefull nodes
    ) 

    # Finally we serialize and dump the output graph to the filesystem
    with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph, "wb") as f:
        f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
    print("%d ops in the final graph." % len(output_graph_def.node))

return output_graph_def

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--model_dir", type=str, default="", help="Model folder to export")
    parser.add_argument("--output_node_names", type=str, default="", help="The name of the output nodes, comma separated.")
   args = parser.parse_args()

   freeze_graph(args.model_dir, args.output_node_names)
```

Comment: How do you call your module? Have you checked that the `model_dir` you provide actually points a folder containing your model?

Comment: I hard coded the path to .ckpt, .index, etc files. The directory is present since it doesn't throw an exception

Comment: Yeah the folder exists but it doesn't mean it points to your model. Check this also. For some reason you cannot get a CheckpointState proto from `tf.train.get_checkpoint_state()`

Comment: I printed the value of tf.train.get_checkpoint_state() and received None. Is there a specific file, which should be included in the root folder for the .ckpt, index, etc files?

Comment: Judging from your message `Export directory doesn't exists.` are you pointing to an existing but empty folder to store your frozen model and not to the folder containing the unfrozen model maybe?

Comment: I do not receive the "export directory doesn't exist" error. I get a : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'model_checkpoint_path' issue and when I check the value of : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'model_checkpoint_path', is a None. In my model_dir folder, I have a .ckpt.data .., .ckpt.index, and ckpt.meta files. Should there be more files?

Comment: I think the problem is that I don't have a specific file named checkpoint in the checkpoint directory?